# Java: Horizontal and Vertical movement is faster than Diagonal movement

Tags: java, math, angle

I have recently calculated for some entities to target one specific entity in the center, and I used this function to decide in which direction for them to travel:

```
double xa = 0, ya = 0;

double targetX = mother.getX();
double targetY = mother.getY();

double deltaX = targetX - x;
double deltaY = targetY - y;
double speed = 0.5d;
double dir = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);

xa += (speed * Math.cos(dir));
ya += (speed * Math.sin(dir));
```

And since then, entities that are moving `diagonally` move a little slower than the entities moving directly `vertically` and `horizontally`. How could I recalculate this so they all move at the same speed?

Comment: Maybe, visually, it looks like its move slower because distance on diagonal direction is largest than horizontaly or vertically. But, speed is always the same.

Comment: I did currently solve my problem in a certain way, if the entity is moving at a `diagonal` direction I just added `0.175` to its x and y

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct.  The distance between successive (`xa`,`xb`) should always be exactly the same distance.

Are you just running this flat out in a loop with no delays or timers? Perhaps what is happening is that `atan2` is optimized to calculate faster when one of its arguments is zero (the vertical and horizontal case), and so it will go around the loop faster.

I suggest you use [`Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20java.util.Date,%20long%29) to make sure your iterations have equal duration, putting your code inside a `TimerTask`.

Comment: I do have it running in a timer, 60 loops per second.